# What are the reasons for the decisions behind implementing strings as an array of chars with a null marker vs other approaches in C?

Tags: c, string

Looking into `C` for the first time, I found that a string is actually a `char[]` - and I was wondering how many different ways there are of implementing a string datatype as a result?

A comment on this question ([Why does a string of N chars require initializing an array of N + 1 chars in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205015/why-does-a-string-of-n-chars-require-initializing-an-array-of-n-1-chars-in-c?noredirect=1#comment97148019_55205015))

> For a string datatype, you need to know the length. You can either have a struct that has a length field (and the char array), or you need a special marker to signal the end of the string. In C the special marker method has been chosen and the marker is a null character

Implies there are just two means of achieving a string structure?

1. A `char[]` with a null marker
2. An object of sorts that provides a pointer to the start of a `char[]` and other necessary metadata

Are there other means of implementing a string datatype? Why did `C` take approach (1)?

Comment: I just assumed that an array would be implemented as a linked list?

Comment: Otherwise... why would you need a struct as the comment suggests? Surely an array provides a means of figuring out the 'last' element without having to hold a NULL byte? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: edited to remove mention of linked lists

Comment: Perhaps you should take a step back, find a beginners book, and read more about arrays?

Comment: "Surely an array provides a means of figuring out the 'last' element without having to hold a NULL byte?" It does not. How would it? In C, it is just a sequence of boxes on a near-infinite wall of boxes. If you have `char[5]`, it's just five boxes in a row that are not in any way different from neighbouring ones; they're not pink, or older, or marked "here goes your string". The pointer just tells you which box is the first. Then you can either choose to say "I'm going to read boxes till I find an empty one" (strat 1) or "The first box I open will tell me how many more boxes I can read" (2)

Comment: My understanding is that they are a contiguous piece of memory divided into some number of spaces that are accessed in order and by an index value starting from `0` (unless working with Windows COM in which case the first index value is `1`). Is that correct @Someprogrammerdude? As such... I don't understand the comment I quoted in my question

Comment: Yes - but when you say `foo[2]` and `bar[2]`, it is actually the second box to the right of the box number `foo` and second box to the right of the box number `bar`, where `foo` could be `1653839` and `bar` could be `8827383` (i.e. `foo[2]` is the same as `*(foo + 2)`, which would here be whatever is in box number `1653841`). There is only one box numbered `0`, and it's typically very, very reserved and will never make an appearance in your code. (I'm simplifying things a lot here, in this analogy, as data type sizes also make a difference.)

Comment: ... I have to ask @Amadan. What is box `0` typically reserved for??

Comment: The start of the memory is where typically you'd find the kernel, in most operating systems. However, everything I've written here is quite simplified. The point is, `foo[0]` is not the zeroth memory location - it is the location that is zero locations offset from wherever `foo` is.

Comment: It was probably a design desicion. NUL terminated strings are very simple because there is no metadata. A string in C is not much more than an array of chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why did C take approach (1)?*

According to *[The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)*, it was to avoid fixing the maximum length of a string, and that their personal experience led them to believe a terminator was more convenient.

> None of BCPL, B, or C supports character data strongly in the language; each treats strings much like vectors of integers and supplements general rules by a few conventions. In both BCPL and B a string literal denotes the address of a static area initialized with the characters of the string, packed into cells. In BCPL, the first packed byte contains the number of characters in the string; in B, there is no count and strings are terminated by a special character, which B spelled `*e`. This change was made partially to avoid the limitation on the length of a string caused by holding the count in an 8- or 9-bit slot, and partly because maintaining the count seemed, in our experience, less convenient than using a terminator.

*Are there other means of implementing a string datatype?*

Nothing significantly different, as long as a string is defined to consist of contiguous bytes.

Comment: There is, actually - ironically, as a linked list. It is not very efficient, but was done for historical and theoretical reasons in e.g. Haskell (where `[Char]` is a linked list of characters that didn't need extra development since they came for free from linked list + char data types; the more efficient data structures like `Data.Text` came later). There's also [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)).

Comment: @Amadan: I figured there would be exceptions, which is why I qualified my statement.

Comment: Thank you - does this mean that strings are typically stored in contiguous memory? What about extremely long strings?

Comment: Strings are not intended to be extremely long. Usually the length of the string does not exceed  20xscreen width. If you need to store and work with the longer ones use table of pointers to the strings

Comment: @ZachSmith: C evolved from a language that represented strings that way, so it retained that heritage. Very large datasets are generally difficult to manage as a single string without some higher level structure over it, even in languages that support string as a built in data type. You would probably rather index the data to speed up future searches than to constantly perform `strstr` on the whole thing each time.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that C was developed primarily to implement the UNIX operating system - text processing was not going to be its focus.

Mapping strings and string operations onto arrays makes sense since, at their core, strings are sequences of character values.  Existing operations on arrays (such that they are) can be applied to strings fairly easily.  Some operations like concatenation become dead easy.

Using a terminator instead of a leading length byte means there’s no upper limit on string length.

There are times when it would be nice to have a real string data type, distinct from an array of `char`.  However, in most C programming, those times are few enough and far enough between that this method is good enough.

Comment: I didn't know that C was developed to implement UNIX :) thanks